# I want to do transform json structure using jolt but iam getting error

Tags: java, json, maven, jolt

I want to fetch the JSON transformation using a jolt

I am trying in my eclipse using maven

```java
package com.transform;

import java.util.List;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.Chainr;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.JsonUtils;

public class transform {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Object> specs =  
        JsonUtils.classpathToList("com.transform//src//main//java//jsoinfiles//spec.json");
        Chainr chainr = Chainr.fromSpec(specs);
        Object inputJSON =  JsonUtils.classpathToObject("com.transform//src//main//java//jsoinfiles//input.json");
        Object transformedOutput = chainr.transform(inputJSON);

        System.out.println(JsonUtils.toPrettyJsonString(transformedOutput));
    }
}
```

When I run the above code I get the following exception;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load 
 JSON map from classPath : 
  com.transform//src//main//java//jsoinfiles//spec.json
at 
com.bazaarvoice.jolt.JsonUtilImpl.classpathToList(JsonUtilImpl.java:225)
at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.JsonUtils.classpathToList(JsonUtils.java:165)
at com.transform.transform.main(transform.java:9)
```

Comment: Welcome. I think you need to post the structure of your project.

Comment: Post your spec and input json then we can check.

Comment: Why do you use **double slash (//)** as path separator? Please use `File.pathSeparator` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's a class path issue, definitely. 
Your code:
        List specs =
        JsonUtils.classpathToList("com.transform//src//main//java//jsoinfiles//spec.json");
        Chainr chainr = Chainr.fromSpec(specs);
        Object inputJSON =  JsonUtils.classpathToObject("com.transform//src//main//java//jsoinfiles//input.json"

There you are using com. transform

Remove that one.
Use the below things.

//src//main//java//jsoinfiles//input.json

And
//src//main//java//jsoinfiles//spec.json

Then check  .

Comment: It's a web application or, simple java application  ? @Abhinav

Comment: Can you post ur project structure, by taking a screen shot.

Comment: this is my project structure    E:\Abhinav kiran\com.transform\src\main\java\com\transform In that transform, I have my java file and JSON files

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest restructuring your project and updating your code accordingly:

Structure:

```
./src/main/java/com/transform/App.java
./src/main/resources/jsoinfiles/spec.json
./src/main/resources/jsoinfiles/input.json
```

Then use the code:

```java
package com.transform;

import java.util.List;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.Chainr;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.JsonUtils;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Object> specs =  
        JsonUtils.classpathToList("/jsoinfiles/spec.json");
        Chainr chainr = Chainr.fromSpec(specs);
        Object inputJSON =  JsonUtils.classpathToObject("/jsoinfiles/input.json");
        Object transformedOutput = chainr.transform(inputJSON);

        System.out.println(JsonUtils.toPrettyJsonString(transformedOutput));
    }
}
```

This is based on the JSONUtilsTest within the jolt project:

https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/json-utils/src/test/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/JsonUtilsTest.java#L131-L133

Comment: is it possible to use objects in memory? instead of the file path?
 for example:
JSONObject or json string.
For a need for dynamic "SPEC" stored in a database.

Comment: `JsonUtils` contains a method `jsonToList(string, encoding)`, which would be a direct swap for `classpathToList` in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind you are getting the error is the class-path that you have mentioned in your code. use the below structure to define your class-path and you would definitely get the error resolved and the desired output.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Object> specs =  
        JsonUtils.classpathToList("/jsoinfiles/spec.json");
        Chainr chainr = Chainr.fromSpec(specs);
        Object inputJSON =  JsonUtils.classpathToObject("/jsoinfiles/input.json");
        Object transformedOutput = chainr.transform(inputJSON);

        System.out.println(JsonUtils.toPrettyJsonString(transformedOutput));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get a file from local drive using the filepathToList and then give a path

```
public class Json {

    @Autowired
    JsonUtils jsonUtils;

    public static void run()   {
        JSONObject payJSON = new JSONObject();
        String transformedJSON = null;
        Object transformedOutput = null;
 
        List<Object> specs = JsonUtils.filepathToList("D:\\JSON\\SPEC.json");
        Chainr chainr = Chainr.fromSpec(specs);
        Object inputJSON = JsonUtils.filepathToObject("D:\\JSON\\Inquiry_Response-Islimited-N.json");
        Object transformedOutput1 = chainr.transform(inputJSON);

        System.out.println(JsonUtils.toPrettyJsonString(transformedOutput1));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run();
    }
 
}
```